# Characters out of order?

Tags: bash, character

I made a short test because it seems the colon character `:` is out of order. The script prints the characters and clearly the colon comes after the `9`, but after running string tests it looks to actually come after the forward slash `/`. What gives?

```
$ cat chartest.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $LANG

for i in {33..126}; do
  printf -v hex "%x" "$i"
  printf "\x$hex"
done

echo
[[ : > 9 ]] && echo true || echo false
[[ : > / ]] && echo true || echo false

$ ./chartest.sh
en_US.UTF-8
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnop
qrstuvwxyz{|}~
false
true
```

I found if I use the old test function it works correctly

```
$ [ : \> 9 ] && echo true || echo false
true
```

Also relevant

http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/COMPAT

Comment: Do you get a different result if you change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`? At my `bash` prompt, `[[ : > 9 ]]` evaluates to true for me (Mac OS X, bash 4.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare strings with [[ > ]], bash uses locale-aware comparison. In en_US.UTF-8, most common punctuation comes before numbers, regardless of ASCII code (or Unicode code-point, for that matter). If you change your locale (or at least LC_COLLATE) to C or C.UTF-8, then you should find that collation works more the way you expect it to.

Note that locale-aware comparison is not so simple as just transliterating codes. I personally find it necessary to set my LANG to C, because otherwise the `sort` utility's handling of spaces wrecks many of my scripts. I have no idea why Ubuntu chooses to do this:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_GB.UTF-8
$ [[ "week night" > "wee knight" ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ [[ "week light" > "wee knight" ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
```